# Error when working with the context in fragment

Tags: android, android-context

everything works. question - well I do? and how can otherwise call contexthow to call this method?

in MyActivity:

```
@Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }
```

in my fragment I call the method:

```
 public void setData(){
        new MyAsincTask(getActivity()){

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Document document) {
                super.onPostExecute(document);
               ........

                getActivity().setTitle("Сотрудники(city:" + city + ",holiday:" + holiday + ")");
            }


        }.execute(link);
    }
```

it works. but if during the process to move to another part of the application crashes

but if you add

```
if (getActivity()!=null)
                getActivity().setTitle("Сотрудники(city:" + city + ",holiday:" + holiday + ")");
```

everything works. question - well I do? and how can otherwise call context

```
12-24 05:18:28.805      460-460/com.managment.pavel.managmentgradle E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.managment.pavel.managmentgradle.fragments.EmployeessList$1.onPostExecute(EmployeessList.java:114)
            at com.managment.pavel.managmentgradle.fragments.EmployeessList$1.onPostExecute(EmployeessList.java:69)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Pass activity context reference to other part of application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fragment had been detached when you navigated to another part of the app, so getActivity will return null. Since it is not meaningful to change the title of an activity that had been destroyed, it is probably OK to just put the null check in like you did.

However this can become a bigger problem if your async task must call back to the activity. I recommend using an event bus such as Otto to pass data from async task back up to the UI.

Here is my blog post on this topic: [Event Bus Usage on Android](http://innodroid.com/blog/post/event-bus-usage-on-android)

Comment: could share a link or example? (using an event bus such as Otto to pass data from async task back up to the UI.)

Comment: Let me see if i can find something

Comment: do not quite understand you)

Comment: Ill try to find a simple example that i like. Or maybe make one

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to a blog post I just made to answer your question. Let me know if this is more understandable now.

Comment: wonderful and clear article (even with my bad English). It is a pity that I have not heard about it before. Under the new Projects necessarily its use.